# How do I generate broadcast storm?

Tags: networking

I started to study networking and I have two cisco switches, and I want generate broadcast storm to test Spanning Tree, How do I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

for gnu ping

```
ping -b -f <bcast addr>
```

This will flood ping the broadcast address however you must be the superuser to do so ( aka root ). In my very limited test sending 2 packets generated over 183 responses so make sure you do not do this on a production network for long.

Comment: Ok, but, how Do I organize copper connections? look how it was:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/823/ciscow.jpg

Comment: I'd hook up a few client machines to the switches and boot them with a linux live cd. Should cause the effects you are looking for.

Comment: Adding a third switch may also help connected A to B, B to C, and C to A. May not be necessary though.

Answer (score 0):

you can do it easily just disable spaning make loop , connect the tow switches using tow cables , and through console go to the ports which you connect to and disable apaning tree :

from switch console 
conf t

interface fastethernet  (interface number)

spanin portfast

repeat this on all the ports connected between switchs , and switch will hang when connect your pc on any port